# Unable to insert null value into nullable string field

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Current project:

- ASP.NET 4.5.2
- MVC 5
- EF 6
- Fluent API, tweaked for stored procedures

I am able to insert null values into everything except for a set of three `nvarchar(MAX)` columns in one table, and it’s driving me batty.

The model:

```
public string SpecialtyEquipment { get; set; }
public string EQAttachments { get; set; }
public string SpecialtySafetyTickets { get; set; }
```

The Fluent API:

```
Jobs.Property(x => x.SpecialtyEquipment).IsOptional();
Jobs.Property(x => x.EQAttachments).IsOptional();
Jobs.Property(x => x.SpecialtySafetyTickets).IsOptional();
```

The table in SQL Server 2012 and it's clearly showing all three columns as `nvarchar(MAX)` and nullable. As this is code-first, I have never touched the database directly.

My (cut down) controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> JobAdditional(JobAdditionalViewModel model) {
  Jobs job = await db.Jobs.FindAsync(model.Job.JobId);
  JobMap jobMap = new JobMap(model.Job, job);
  db.Entry(job).State = EntityState.Modified;
  await db.SaveChangesAsync();
  return RedirectToAction("JobDetail", new { id = model.Job.RecruiterJobId });
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class JobAdditionalViewModel {
  public Jobs Jobs { get; set; } // to display most of the current job
  public JobModel Job { get; set; } // to edit a specific portion of the current job
}
```

My form model:

```
public class JobModel {
  public Guid? JobId { get; set; }
  [DisplayName("Specialty Equipment (not on prior page)")]
  public string SpecialtyEquipment { get; set; }
  [DisplayName("Specialty Attachments (not on prior page)")]
  public string EQAttachments { get; set; }
  [DisplayName("Specialty Safety Tickets (not on prior page)")]
  public string SpecialtySafetyTickets { get; set; }
}
```

My mapping model:

```
public JobMap(JobModel model, Jobs job) {
  job.SpecialtyEquipment = model.SpecialtyEquipment.Trim();
  job.EQAttachments = model.EQAttachments.Trim();
  job.SpecialtySafetyTickets = model.SpecialtySafetyTickets.Trim();
}
```

All errors flag my mapping model, and they flag any one of the three when there is no content in the `textarea` -- that is, if it a value that is nothing, or whitespace that gets trimmed to nothing.

I have tried all variations of “handling” strings of no content, and nothing seems to work. Every single time, no matter how I try to handle zero content (an empty `textarea`), I get a `System.NullReferenceException`.

For the record, these all fail:

```
= (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SpecialtyEquipment.Trim()) ? null : model.SpecialtyEquipment.Trim());
= (model.SpecialtyEquipment.Trim().Length == 0 ? null : model.SpecialtyEquipment.Trim());
```

I have even tried to substitute the `null` with `string.Empty`, to no avail.

In fact, the only method which seems to work is replacing everything after the equals in my mapping model with `null;`. Yup, that’s right -- force-feeding it null values:

```
= null;
```

Instead of trying a ternary operator for which null is one option is the only thing that will actually work.

In fact, I have a number of different nullable columns scattered throughout the project that I *can* insert null values into without any problems whatsoever. All I have to do is cast the null to a nullable version of the column type:

```
(Guid?)null;
(int?)null;
(decimal?)null;
```

and it works perfectly.

But since you cannot cast a null as a nullable string, how do you handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line would throw `NullReferenceException` on `model.SpecialtyEquipment.Trim()` if `model.SpecialtyEquipment` were null

```
= (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.SpecialtyEquipment.Trim()) ? null : model.SpecialtyEquipment.Trim());
```

This line would throw `NullReferenceException` on `model.SpecialtyEquipment.Trim()` if `model.SpecialtyEquipment` where null.

```
= (model.SpecialtyEquipment.Trim().Length == 0 ? null : model.SpecialtyEquipment.Trim());
```

To break it down again you are getting the `NullReferenceException` (NRE) because the value of `model.SpecialtyEquipment` is null and now you are calling a method on that null value. You can duplicate it by doing this

```
((string)null).Trim(); // will throw a NRE
```

This would be the best solution

```
model.SpecialtyEquipment = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.SpecialtyEquipment) // an actual null/empty check without the possibility of a NRE
    ? null 
    : model.SpecialtyEquipment.Trim();
```

[string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you are using an older version of the framework that does not support this method than do both checks like so:

```
model.SpecialtyEquipment = model.SpecialtyEquipment == null || model.Trim().Length == 0 
    ? null 
    : model.SpecialtyEquipment.Trim();
```

Both of these would guard against a NRE being thrown by checking for null and not performing an operation on the string if it is null.

Comment: Holy. Mary. Mother. Of. F##K ME WITH A F##KING POGO STICK. Please wait while I flail my cranium against the nearest masonry. So… it's the `.Trim()` that screws everything up? How can that be? When the form gets returned from the client the fields *can* hold just white space, which should be trimmed. That trimmed content is either not empty, or empty. So a check is done for empty… and it fails because `string = "";` is the same as `string = null;`? That’s a new one for me.

Comment: So… if we had `var string = "";`, would `string.Trim()` also throw a NRE?

Comment: @RenéKåbis - no, not in that situation.

Comment: @RenéKåbis - Best way it to use IsNullOrWhiteSpace OR 2 checks with an AND operator (see updated answer)

Comment: Pardon me if I have a bit of a meltdown in the corner over here, but one of the things I learned very early on in the history of the Web (late 90s) is that form fields may have empty values, but they *are* values. The only reason why you *might* be able to check a form field for a null value is if the underlying framework does a `"" == null` translation, and says “OK, it is null” even when `value = ""`. But otherwise any operation you do on the returned value of a form field *should be* no different than if you were working with `value = ""`. Whelp, there goes a 20-year concept out the window…

Comment: @RenéKåbis - maybe that's a valid check in another language? In c# though the CLR will not implicitly convert anything to null nor allow you to execute instance operations/members on a null pointer. When dealing with strings you will then always have to execute a double check or use one of the convenience methods.

Comment: My sticking point is that form fields that are being returned empty are being interpreted as `value = null` instead of the `value = ""` that they *should* be handled as. As in, an empty value, but a value nonetheless. Still, excellent explanation above, very much appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @RenéKåbis - ah. I guess if they come back with `null` and you were expecting an empty string the best place to look would be starting with the browser in the debug console to see what is transmitted across the line back to the server. After that see how that data is interpreted by your controller when your model is bound.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` and avoid calling `Trim()` when the string is null:

```
job.SpecialtyEquipment = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.SpecialtyEquipment) ? null : model.SpecialtyEquipment.Trim();
```

Comment: Had to flag Igor’s answer as the correct one, as he took the time to thoroughly beat me about the head with the full explanation. As in, C# seems to pre-emptively convert a submitted empty form field into a null form field before anything could possibly be done with it. Apparently `"" = null` where form fields are concerned.